# Getting the SUM from other tables rows based off a remote foreign key value in original table

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables, `vehicle_service_invoice`, `vehicle_service_labor`, `vehicle_service_parts`. All of these tables relate to each other using the `invoice` row on each table. I want to make a view of these three tables called `vehicle_service` that will show the total price for parts and labor as they are connected to the invoice table.

With a single table, I'd `SUM` the `extended` column and `GROUP BY` the `invoice` column on both the `vehicle_service_labor` and `vehicle_service_parts`. But how would I connect this information back to the vehicle_service_invoice's invoice column so that it would display correctly?

I'd want it to look something like this ...

**vehicle_service**

```
vehicle date       po      invoice labor  parts  sublet total
008     2013-01-07 1301070 1111    204.00 129.11 0.00    333.11
008     2013-01-21 1301210 1122    521.00 584.70 0.00   1105.70
003     2013-02-07 1302070 2211     34.00   0.00 0.00     34.00
004     2013-02-18 1302180 2222     51.00  70.14 0.00    121.14
003     2013-03-18 1303180 3311     51.00  70.14 0.00    121.14
003     2013-04-18 1204180 4411     51.00 412.83 0.00    463.83
008     2013-04-25 1304250 4422     68.00 269.82 0.00    337.82
006     2013-05-25 1305250 5511    204.00  17.85 0.00    221.85
007     2013-05-29 1305290 5522    442.00 299.35 0.00    741.35
006     2013-06-29 1306290 6611    136.00   0.00 0.00    136.00
003     2013-07-16 1307160 7711    136.00   0.00 0.00    136.00
004     2013-08-16 1308160 8811    187.00 172.53 0.00    359.53
003     2013-09-16 1309160 9911    136.00 140.47 0.00    276.47
007     2013-10-30 1310300 1011     34.00  29.83 0.00     63.83
008     2013-11-30 1311300 0000    136.00 175.25 0.00    311.25
```

These are the tables I'm sourcing the information from.

**vehicle_service_invoice**

```
invoice date       unit odometer sublet sub     po
1111    2013-01-07 008  34863    0         0.00 1301070
1122    2013-01-21 008  36435    0      1105.70 1301210
2211    2013-02-07 003  35594    0        34.00 1302070
2222    2013-02-18 004  49079            121.14 1531214
3311    2013-03-18 003  36158    0       121.14 1303180
4411    2013-04-18 003           0       463.83 1204180
4422    2013-04-25 008  36516    0       337.82 1304250
5511    2013-05-25 006  48807    0       221.85 1305250
5522    2013-05-29 007  37133    0       741.35 1305290
7711    2013-06-06 003  38535    0       136.00 1307160
8811    2013-06-16 004  51588    0       359.53 1308160
9911    2013-07-16 003  39302    0       276.47 1309160
1011    2013-07-30 007  39675    0        63.83 1310300
0000    2013-08-30 008  40027    0       311.25 1311300
```

**vehicle_service_labor**

```
invoice labor           hours extended description
1111    Pick Up         0     0        Pick Up & Del...
1111    Fuel Leak       3     204      Locate fuel l...
1122    PM Inspection   5     340      Preventative ...
1122    NYS Inspection  0.5   45       NYS Inspection
1122    Tires           1     68       Breakdown, mo...
1122    Lights          0.5   34       Repair front ...
1122    Receptacle      0.5   34       Replace broke...
2211    Flat            0.5   34       Repair Rear Flat
2222    Door            0.75  51       Remove broken...
3311    Door            0.75  51       Remove broken...
4411    Mirror          0.75  51       Remove and Re...
4422    Batteries       1     68       Check batteri...
5511    Pick Up         0     0        Pick Up & Del...
5511    Brakes          3     204      Add fluid, br...
5522    PM Inspection   5     340      Preventative ...
5522    NYS Inspection  0.5   34       NYS Inspection
5522    Leak            1     68       Checkout Cab ...
7711    Flat Call       2     136      Service Call ...
8811    LOF             2     136      Change Oil in...
8811    Flat            0.75  51       Raise and Sup...
9911    LOF             2     136      Change Oil in...
1011    Door            0.5   34       Check Out Doo...
0000    Flats           2     136      Service call ...
```

**vehicle_service_parts**

```
invoice part             qty sale   extended description
1111    Fuel Treatment   1    28.73  28.73   Enertech
1111    Fuel Filter      1    76.66  76.66   PF7698
1111    Antifreeze       1    23.72  23.72   Glychol
1122    Engine Oil       16    4.48  71.68   15W40
1122    Oil Filter       1    34.76  34.76   FL1995
1122    Air Filter       2    31.26  62.52   FA1618
1122    Fuel Additive    1    14.33  14.33   Stanadyne
1122    Coolant Additive 1    12.95  12.95   DCA60L
1122    Recepticle Cover 1    35     35      KUS 091-3WH
1122    22575r16 10 P... 2   165    333      
1122    Tire Disposal... 2     8     16      Tire Disposal
1122    Tire Waste Sa... 1     2.25   2.25   NYS Tire Fee
1122    Mini Lightbulb   1     3.13   3.13   3156
1122    Bulb             2     1.04   2.08   194
2222    Pivot-Sprint Bar 1    31.11  31.11   Brapivot
2222    Door Check Right 1    39.03  39.03   15721
3311    Pivot-Sprint Bar 1    31.11  31.11   Brapivot
3311    Door Check Right 1    39.03  39.03   15721
4411    Mirror Assemb... 1   412.83 412.83   9C2Z17683CA
4422    Battery          2   134.91 269.82   665MF
5511    Brake Fluid      1     7.95  7.95    Brake Fluid
5511    Brake Parts C... 1     9.9   9.9     Brake Clean
5522    Engine Oil       16    4.48  71.68   15W40
5522    Oil Filter       1    24.86  24.86   FL2016
5522    Fuel Filter      1   109.58 109.58   PF7852
5522    Air Filter       1    69.95  69.95   PA4171
5522    Fuel Additive    1    14.33  14.33   Stanadyne
5522    Silicone Sealant 1     8.95   8.95   Silicone
8811    Engine Oil       16    4.48  71.68   15W40
8811    Oil Filter       1    24.86  24.86   FL2016
8811    Antifreeze       1    23.8   23.8    FYA - Ford Yellow
8811    Fuel Treatment   1    28.73  28.73   Enertech
8811    Windshield Wa... 1     2.25   2.25   Windshield Fluid
8811    Coolant Additive 1    12.95  12.95   DCA60L
8811    Power Steerin... 1     8.26   8.26   PSF
9911    Engine Oil       16    4.48  71.68   15W40
9911    Oil Filter       1    24.86  24.86   FL2016
9911    Fuel Treatment   1    28.73  28.73   Enertech
9911    Windshield Wa... 1     2.25   2.25   Windshield
9911    Coolant Additive 1    12.95  12.95   DCA60L
1011    Magnetic Jamb... 1    29.83  29.83   19171
0000    10 Ply Tire      1   165    165      255/75r16lt
0000    Tire Disposal... 1     8      8      Tire Disposal
0000    Tire Waste Sa... 1   2.25   2.25     NYS Tire Fee
```

There is a bit of caution with this data, as it's there for illustrative purposes only to show you what I mean, and the type of data that I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subqueries to get the totals from other tables.
To be able to add the two subtotals together, use another subquery:

```
SELECT *, labor + parts AS total
FROM (SELECT unit AS vehicle,
             date,
             po,
             invoice,
             (SELECT TOTAL(extended)
              FROM vehicle_service_labor
              WHERE invoice = vehicle_service_invoice.invoice
             ) AS labor,
             (SELECT TOTAL(extended)
              FROM vehicle_service_parts
              WHERE invoice = vehicle_service_invoice.invoice
             ) AS parts
      FROM vehicle_service_invoice)
ORDER BY date,
         invoice
```